# Need for privacy manifest blinkid-iOS

Tags: microblink, blinkid

At WWDC23 Apple announced that apps and SDKs that make use of certain "required reason" APIs etc will need to provide a privacy manifest.

Does blinkid-iOS need to include this manifest?

Is this update on the roadmap for the team? I appreciate that enforcement won't happen until Spring 2024 but I wanted to make contact so that we can plan our own app releases to take this into account.

Here’s some useful references:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_data_use_in_privacy_manifests

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10060/

Thanks

I tried to check if blink id ios had a privacy manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Apple's documentation for [upcoming third-party SDK requirements](https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/), the BlinkID SDK is still not listed and does not repackage any of the SDKs from the mentioned list, so the manifest has still not been added to the SDK itself.

However, it is on the roadmap to add the privacy manifest to the BlinkID SDK in future releases.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. It great to know that any of the SDK's listed is not used.
I would like to highlight, that the list of SDK's mentioned is not exhaustive. If the SDK uses any of these API's listed here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api
Then the author is required to provide the required reason in the privacy manifest file along with the reason code. Apps using blinkID will be needed to submit with the privacy manifest file.
Announcement here. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=r1henawx

Comment: UserDefaults is most common of all api's where it is used more than often + is a candidate for "Describing use of required reason API". thanks for your time and double checking on this. appreciate it.

Comment: Of course, and thank you for the detailed feedback. The privacy manifest will definitely be added in future releases. I can notify you here once this is implemented in the SDK.

Comment: Hello team, Any updates on this. starting from tomorrow Apple will start sending warnings to apps who have missing privacy manifest SDK in their project. And 1st May is a hard stop to non compliant apps. Thanks

Comment: @PranKishore yes! The BlinkID 6.6.0 SDK has been released and it contains the Privacy Manifest. You can find it here: 
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/releases/tag/v6.6.0