# Is Apple Privacy Manifest a must?

Tags: ios, xcode, privacy, ios-privacy-settings

1. NSPrivacyTracking, NSPrivacyTrackingDomains, NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes, NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes If none of these conditions apply
2. https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements/
   If the library is not in the list of libraries mentioned by Apple

Is PrivacyInfo a must in the above two situations??

I made a request to the developer of the library I use, but there was no response. (FSCalendar)

But I don't see anything to add to PrivacyInfo either. What should I do in this case?

Comment: As per this reply, we may not worry about the pods which are not in the App Doc's list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77793288/2033377. Having said that, this can be discovered only if we submit the app to the app store and apple issues a warning or a rejection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a must:
Hard deadline 1st May:
Read here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3d8a9yyh

As per this news

even if your app does not contain the library, in the list. you have to check manually if your app code or your 3rd party code uses the privacy required reason api. list of API's described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api

Here is one scanner tool which might help you do this:
https://github.com/omarzl/ios_17_required_reason_api_scanner/tree/binary_analyzer

Apple documentation to read all about it. and more in it's sub pages:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35824757)